# Bug on session switch in https

Tags: session, language, https, localisation

I have created two views, one for English and one for the French.
The default view is French.
When the user chooses the English view there are switched to the French view when switching to https.

I have not found anything in the configuration of magento to resolve this bug.

Comment: In "System > Configuration > Web > Session Validation Settings" what do you have for "Use SID on Frontend"?

Comment: ...or do the two views maybe have different base urls?

Comment: Hi Strauss, any update on this question? or can you respond to the comments?

Answer (score 3):

just make the store https only.

If a session is created in http context, it is not available in https context because of security reasons.